# Error while installing Odoo

Tags: centos, odoo, odoo-8

**Finished Dependency Resolution Error**

**Package:**  `odoo-8.0_20150617-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)`

**Requires:** python(abi) = 2.7

**Installed:** python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.6

**Available:** python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (test)
               python(abi) = 2.6

trying using `--skip-broken` to work around the problem

trying running: `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

**Steps Which I Followed**

1. installed the pstgresql 9.4.4
2. updated the python 2.6 to 2.7
3. Configured odoo repository
4. tried to install odoo using yum install odoo

Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: @ Atul Jain sorry i am not expert in python.How can i get full traceback

Comment: show here what steps you followed from beginning

Comment: follow these links https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-install-openerp-on-centos-4391

Comment: I have installed odoo by using this document 
https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Odoo using this document.
https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/